# ReactiveMongo Pagination with Count

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am trying to implement Pagination with Reactive Mongo.

```
def get(page: Int, pageSize: Int, filter: JsObject = Json.obj()): Future[Seq[Thing]] = {
    val actualPage = if(page > 1) page else 1
    collection
      .find(filter)
      .options(QueryOpts(skipN = (actualPage - 1) * pageSize, batchSizeN = pageSize))
      .cursor[Thing]()
      .collect[Seq](pageSize, Cursor.FailOnError[Seq[Thing]]())
}
```

This works and returns me a sequence of documents filtering by the `page` and `pageSize`. The problem is I have no idea how many results match the specified query, so I cant tell how many `page`'s exist.

Is there a way I can also get a `$count` as part of the same query? Or do I need to resort to querying the database a second time with the below?

```
collection.count(filter)
```

Ideally I would change my return type to `Future[Page[Seq[Thing]]]` where `Page` would contain the total result count. e.g.

```
case class Page[T](results: Seq[T], count: Int)
```

Comment: Have you first "designed" a working query in the MongoShell?